# Can't import @fullcalendar in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar

import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue'

throws

- ../../ullcalendar/vue in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib?{"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["env",{"modules":false,"targets":{"browsers":["> 2%"],"uglify":true}}]],"plugins":["transform-object-rest-spread",["transform-runtime",{"polyfill":false,"helpers":false}],["babel-plugin-root-import",{"rootPathPrefix":"@","rootPathSuffix":"./resources/assets/js"}]]}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/assets/js/views/main/Dashboard.vue

Comment: try `'@/fullcalendar'` instead of `'@fullcalendar'`.  You need a slash after the @.

Answer (score 0):

Try `'@/fullcalendar/vue'` you need the have slash / after the @ you can even do `../fullcalendar/vue` or `./fullcalendar/vue` depends on where your file is located. If that doesn't solve the problem check your package json if you have downloaded the fullcalendar and put the FullCalender into the components. But first look if you have installed the fullcalendar if not the a npm install once again.

```
export default {
  components: {
    FullCalendar 
  }
}
```